# at nextjs router. how to get path after router push

Tags: reactjs, next.js, path, router

I am making a site and this is some part of them.
let's say I am in "home" page. and I will go to "service" page.

I want to get path of "service" page. (I want to get like "/service", after "router push".

but my code show "/" (before "router push"'s path)

How to get present path after "router push", not previous path?

thanks.

`import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

const SideBar = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const handleClick = (e, path) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    props.toggleMenu()
    router.push(path)
    console.log( router.pathname ) // this shows path "before router push"    
  }
 return (
    <div className="sidebar">
       <Link href="/">
         <a onClick={(e)=> handleClick(e, "/")} >HOME</a>
       </Link>
       <Link href="/service">
         <a onClick={(e)=> handleClick(e, "/service")} >SERVICE</a>
       </Link>
    </div>
 )
}
export default SideBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
  console.log(url);
};
router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
return () => {
  router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
};
```

This "url" is the value that I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By the time that console.log is triggered, you haven't navigated to the new route yet.

If you want to console.log AFTER you've routed, you need to set up a function to trigger after the route has changed.

In that case, you need to set up an "on" event listener in your _app.js file:

```
router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => console.log(router.pathname))
```

Comment: const handleRouteChange = (url) => {  
      console.log(url)             
    }
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    }


//This "url" is the value that I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use router.pathname to get the current path. router.asPath to get the current path with query.

Lets say your url is http://localhost:3000/service?serviceId=1

```
const router = useRouter();

console.log(router.pathname); // returns /service
console.log(router.asPath); //returns /service?serviceId=1
```

Comment: Thanks for you replyment. 
router.pathname returns "before router push path"..
and, router.asPath reruns same.. too.
(I edited my qestion. I mean "router.pathname" returns path name of previous path.

Comment: I suggest you try the answer of @Josh.

router.events doc can be found [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use window.location, then you can use it with setTimout.

```
const handleClick = (e, path) => {
    router.push(path)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log( window.location.pathname)
    }, 0)   
  }
```

The reason I use `window.location` here is the `router.pathname`, or `asPath` is not working for me when I tried other answers (not sure what reason). But the main idea here is `setTimeout` to make it async so it can be triggered when sync codes have finished excuting.